# Detect FN-Key on Mac using Javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, keypress, hotkeys

i want to capture the fn-key on the Mac keyboard in my CMS application. Binding an event to the key and logging the codes showed me that the keycode returned by the fn-key is 0 (zero).

I am tempted to take that as a given - but before i implement this, i wanted to check back with you guys and see whether you think this is the correct code for this key or if it merely means the system has no idea how to interpret that specific key event.

Would be great to get some input here.

Thanks!

Comment: I just found out that i receive a zero as well when using the >/< key.

Comment: @user1018787 May I ask why you need this ? seems very odd to use such key combination for a CMS.

Comment: I am providing a 100% live interface in the CMS, meaning that there are tons of controls spread all over the page. In order to allow the user to preview the page as-is, i provide a hotkey to blend out all the controls in real-time. I bound the CTRL key to this and it works well. However, there are two types of controls: configuration buttons AND delete buttons. The latter are usually not visible, but only appear when you keep the ALT button pressed. However, in some cases those buttons will overlap and so the user will press CTRL+ALT, but then clicking on a control will trigger the contextmenu

Comment: That is why i seek a different hotkey instead of CTRL. The cmd key would work (metakey), but is used like ALT-TAB is used on windows, to switch applications, so it is not a good idea. The shift key will trigger a text selection once the user clicks. And i see no other alternative.

Comment: Sorry for the commentflood. After some further research and testing i came to the conclusion that i will use META+ALT for the special case treatment. This works well as the system does not recognize ALT+META+TAB as META+TAB. And clicking is possible too - no context menu appearing. The question above however, might still be interesting for others so i leave it open for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but I think you won't really be able to capture the Fn key like you would the CTRL key. Fn + some other key will trigger the actual keydown or keypress since it's there to allow you to hit the F1-F12 keys. You might be able to use the shift key, but make sure that it doesn't do a text selection.

In jQuery I would do `$("#my-element").disableSelection()` and then see if the Shift + click works the way you want it to.

Comment: I think you are right about the FN-key. Thank you for the suggestion as well, but i decided to take another route altogether by making use of the meta (Apple CMD) key. In any case this is good input!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you can capture the fn key just as if it were shift, opt or cmd. On mountain Lion you will be able to press twice fn to bring up dictation. Even on lion you can map fn as a control in some games (see HoN, or Heroes of Newerth, where you can use fn as a control key). Problem is I don't know how and I can't find a way to do it. But, as I said, I'm pretty sure you can use it that way.

I don't think this would work on windows because of bootcamp drivers, and I really hope someone comes up with a solution for this on bootcamp, as I hate where the fn-ctrl keys are placed when I am in Windows.